# finding the slope of perlin noise

Tags: processing, perlin-noise

I created a random generated terrain using 1d perlin noise, with the `noise()` function built into processing. I store the values in a 1d array.
I need to draw a line perpendicular to the current x position of the mouse.
I am using the [example code](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html) from the processing documentation.
I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance,
Arad.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you shared your code. From what I can tell, the example code on the processing documentation returns a number.